# Calcular diferença entre datas em Horas no R

Tags: r

Tenho duas datas em formato data e hora.

```
Data1 <- 20/01/2018 20:33:58
Data2 <- 21/01/2018 20:23:48
```

A diferença, em horas, é de `23:49:50`. Como é feito o cálculo desta diferença no R?

Além disso, preciso saber se esta diferença acima tem mais ou menos de 24 horas. Como faço para fazer esta verificação?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `difftime`, mas lembre-se que a datas devem estar em formato em [`Date-Time`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html) ou [`Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Dates.html).

Para transformar `character` em `Date-Time`:

```
  Data1 <- "20/01/2018 20:33:58"
  Data2 <- "21/01/2018 20:23:48"

  # Converter
  Data1 <- strptime(Data1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  Data2 <- strptime(Data2, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

  class(Data1)
  > [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Calcular a diferença:

```
  difer <- difftime(Data2, Data1, units = 'hour')
  > Time difference of 23.99722 hours
```

Não sei o contexto que você quer utilizar, mas você pode usar um `if else` para saber se a diferença é maior ou menor que 24h.

```
  if(difer[[1]] > 24) {
    "fazer algo se mais que 24"
  }else{
    "fazer algo se menos que 24h"
  }
```

Comment: Meus campos estão em formato "character" e não estou conseguindo fazer a sua sugestão. Como converter caracter para data e hora(datetime)?

Comment: @BrunoAvila editei a resposta explicando como converter de `character` para `Date-Time`.